# How do I create the asp.net Identity tables manually with migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I would like the asp.net Identity tables to exist in my database, and as well, have the corresponding respective code-first models generated before I actually run the mvc app and create a user, so that I may code some logic against these classes before hand.  Is there a way that I can create these tables/classes with migrations manually?

Comment: You may also want to check out this project: **[ASP.NET Identity Database](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6780f8e4-d204-4e88-83c2-853098727ffb)** (project template), it can help to create and customize ASP.NET Identity Database manually with [SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/tools.aspx).

Comment: That looks really interesting!  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add it manually in your database, you'll have to write it in a Structured Query Language ;)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId]    NVARCHAR (150)  NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey]     NVARCHAR (300)  NOT NULL,
    [Model]          VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] NVARCHAR (32)   NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
    [Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [User_Id]    NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] (
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]            NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PasswordHash]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Discriminator] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MigrationId] ASC, [ContextKey] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [LoginProvider] ASC, [ProviderKey] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_Id]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]([User_Id] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]([UserId] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RoleId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([RoleId] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([UserId] ASC);

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;

GO
```

That code just pasted into your database editor should be able to create all the default tables for Identity.

That being said, if you don't mind me asking, what kind of logic are you trying to add in?

Comment: Well, I was getting ready to write a linq statement that queries the AspNetUsers table for emails, but realized I needed to extend the that table with the email property and then generate the models first.  This is my first go at the new membership system, and I had no idea how the table schema should be wired/mapped. There is very little documentation on this new membership system.

Comment: Ah ok. I agree, there is very little in terms of documentation on it thus far... Hopefully more will come out soon.

Ironically enough, I just added in emails into my project using identity. There's a really nice article on how to do it.
[this article here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.in/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html) should tell you everything on how to set up e-mail confirmation. Or at least setting up how to add e-mails as a viable column to your registration process

Comment: Did you implement this solution? Did it work for you? Please accept as an answer if so.

Comment: No, I never actually implemented this solution.  I went a different route.  I ended up just writing code that would automatically create a user when the code runs for the first time, so that the tables would generate by themselves.  Feels like I took the easy way out, but oh well.  I don't doubt that your solution works, though, I just chose an easier direction for my particular situation.

Comment: @user1206480, could you post your solution then, and mark it as an answer, so we all can learn from it? thank you.

Comment: My solution didn't actually resolve my question which is why I didn't post it as an answer. I still would like to see an example on how to explicitly create the database via migrations.

Comment: I get about 20 errors with this script, the first one being       >There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.AspNetUsers' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id'.

Comment: Did you copy over the whole script? If so, try creating the primary keys before the foreign keys using my script. If you would like an example of it, I can provide one

Comment: @DylanCorriveau I got the same foreign key errors. Moving the foreign key creation to after the primary key creation resolved the errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dylan Corriveau's answer works. However, if you are trying to login with these tables.. the userManager.FindAsync will cause a 500 error (Invalid UserId). the User_Id in AspNetUserClaims should be UserId.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Dylan Corriveau's answer and I have some column fields missing when creating(HttpPost) the new user data for the "**AspNetUsers**" table.

The missing fields are here. You can add these fields to your table if you're facing the same problem.

```
[NormalizedUserName]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Email]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[NormalizedEmail]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[EmailConfirmed]    bit NULL,
[ConcurrencyStamp]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumber]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumberConfirmed]  bit NULL,
[TwoFactorEnabled]  bit NULL,
[LockoutEnd]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[LockoutEnabled]    bit NULL,
[AccessFailedCount] int NULL
```

and the **AspNetRoles** is missing

```
[NormalizedName]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ConcurrencyStamp]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
```