# AspNet 4.5 VS 2013 Remote memberShip Database

Tags: database, authentication, asp.net-membership, .net-4.5

I am creating a new Web Application including WebForms, WebApi, and MVC.
I have already a remote SQL server 2008 for old web sites and MemberShip (VS2010 & .Net 4.0)
How can I make new web application to use my sql database to authenticate instead of AspNet-xxxx.mdf.
( I remember a tool with VS2010 and .Net 4.0 to do so)

Thanks.

Comment: I Found this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008174/how-do-i-create-the-asp-net-identity-tables-manually-with-migrations)

Comment: It's seems to be quite simple.
Only change connectionString in Web.Config.
Creation of tables into remote database is automatic.
Thanks.