# c# Identity userManager.FindAsync Invalid UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I am using Asp.net Identity to authorize logins. I can register accounts, but I cannot login with them. I am getting 500 error (Invalid Column Name) when this function is called.

```
    try
    {
         user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, 
            context.Password);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Invalid column name 'UserId'.
    }
```

**EDIT**

Stack Trace

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<EnsureClaimsLoaded>d__5f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at GroceryAppApi.Providers.ApplicationOAuthProvider.<GrantResourceOwnerCredentials>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\bitbucket\Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs:line 36
```

Also, I manually created the database using this link..

[How do I create the asp.net Identity tables manually with migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008174/how-do-i-create-the-asp-net-identity-tables-manually-with-migrations)

**EDIT**

AspNetUsers

[image]

Schema 
[image]

AspNetUsers C# Class

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        ApplicationUser user = null;
        try
        {
             user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide any error message or something?

Comment: The error message is "Invalid column name 'UserId'

Comment: post your User table schema and your User model.

Comment: @AmiNadimi Posted

Comment: "Invalid column name 'UserId'" -> there is no column 'UserId'

Comment: Also post your user model which should be a C# class

Comment: @JanMer Should there be a UserId column in AspNetUsers table?

Comment: @AmiNadimi Sorry, misread your comment. Posted the c# class.

Comment: if you have overridden  `FindAsync` method, it might be good to look inside and search for any usage of `UserId` there.

Comment: somewhere in your code you have referenced `UserId`, search for it and  you will find the point of failure. change it to `User.Id`

Comment: @AmiNadimi I did not override the FindAsync method.. However, I did find AspNetUserLogin uses UserId.. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: Ok, so your DB looks fine but where do you try to log in? In your controller?

Comment: no! AspNetUserLogin  is only related to external logins and has no role in this situation. at this point i think the only way is to examine the full stack trace of the error. post the full error or examine it your self. see if you can find the table being queried.

Comment: @JanMer I try to login using the tokenEndpoint. The built in login for identity

Comment: @AmiNadimi Posted stack trace

Comment: Can you post the code in this file?    ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

Comment: @SSharp posted the class.. I did not create this class ( Default asp.net identity) except for the edits for try/catch around the userManager.FindASync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the UserId field in a test database to match your AspNetUserClaims table. Normally, the field is named UserId, rather than User_Id like yours is. When I made this small change and tried to get a token from the project, the result was an invalid column name 'UserId'.

To solve this alter your AspNetUserClaims table to remove the underscore from that field. It should then hopefully work. Basically your FindAsync is failing to find that column when it goes to fetch the user and all the related tables.

Comment: Thank you so much.. This was hard for me to debug because I did not know which tables are being queried by the userManager.FindAsync function.

Comment: @Mocha Glad I could help. You weren't far off. What I've done in the past for this is to use the local db that it generates and then script out all the tables for the identity stuff. Then for sure you know you are getting the correct tables/fields. Then swapped out the context etc...